# Windows 7 stuck in a reboot loop

Tags: windows, reboot

My Laptop is stuck in a reboot loop. Every time I'm going to turn it on it just displays the windows 7 logo and then it then give me options to enter windows in safe mode or enter windows normally. Which doesn't matter which I choose because the same thing happens over and over rebooting in a loop.

Does anyone know how to fix this.
I'm running windows 7 ultimate 32 bit

Comment: Try pressing the F8 key before Windows boots to get other options, such as "last known good configuration".  What did you do to put the laptop in this state?

Comment: I let my laptop stayed overnyt I was downloading a video and when I turned it on again it resulted in to the reboot loop. what should i do after i choose "last known good configuration"?

Comment: What download program where you using?  What are the auto-powerdown settings for this laptop (i.e. what are the chances that the download finished before the PC goes to sleep)?  Was the laptop running on battery or AC adapter?  After you choose one of the boot options such as "last known good configuration", the laptop should try to boot.

Comment: What brand and model of laptop is it??

Comment: I was using internet download manager. The laptop was running on ac adapter. The same thing happened when i choose "last known..." I'm using Toshiba L300 satellite