# How to troubleshoot and analyze Windows infinite shutdown or reboot screen

Tags: windows-10, crash, shutdown, reboot

I have *Thinkpad E520* notebook with *windows 10* installed on it.

when I am trying restart/shutdown, in shutdown screen Windows go to infinite loop .

It show **restarting/shutdown** message and computer never **reboot/shutdown** unless I hold shutdown button.

Is there way like crash dump analysis to analyze this issue?

Comment: My preliminary search suggests that others may have asked the same question and found no effective answers :(

http://superuser.com/questions/918248/windows-8-1-update-infinite-reboot-loop-we-couldnt-complete-the-updates-un
http://superuser.com/questions/549649/windows-8-infinite-reboot-loop
http://superuser.com/questions/424151/windows-7-stuck-in-a-reboot-loop

This may be beyond the scope of complexity that superuser can address.

Comment: @r_alex_hall i dont search for solution.  i search for way to get log or sonething that find reason of problem

Comment: I don't expect you'd find much that's helpful if you looked at logs. Windows startup repair examines many possible causes of boot failure (in this case, boot failure that restarts the computer in an infinite reboot loop). And, uh, you are searching for a solution. That's why you want to identify the cause :)

Comment: @r_alex_hall it is not infinite loop of reboot.my computet dont reboot and lock in reboot screen

Comment: So you mean your computer gets stuck during shutdown and never shuts down completely; it hangs at the lock screen?